# Who "owns" package name?

Tags: android, google-play

We currently use a app creator that creates the app package for us. They use an app name convention that have their domain name in the url, ex: com.theirname.ourapp

We are working on a new native app, and will stop using the app creator that we must pay monthly and also did not cover all our needs.

My question is: Do they own the "com.theirname.ourapp" package name? or could we deploy the new app using the same name? We have almost 100K installs, and will not like to star fresh with a new package name. Could they ask or force us to stop using "their" package name?

Thanks,
Luis

Comment: That is a question for your attorney. You would also need the signing keystore; otherwise, whether you have rights to that name or not is immaterial.

Comment: (from a purely technical point of view) the package name is, at least, linked to the certificate used to sign the apk. If you don't have the certificate, and can't get it, then you can't really do much

Answer (score 0):

The package name is the smaller. The problem i can see is the  key. When you create an app you need to generate de APK. APK is the package to install the app id all devices, but the updates need a new one APK signed with the same key. The package you can change  and sometimees give you problems, you nd to be carefull with that, but the key always has to be the same. The key has a passwords and then you need to know too.

Answer (score 0):

In the wide world of Android, no-one owns the package name, ignoring legal questions like trademark or copyright. If you are interested in these then you should consult a lawyer, not stackoverflow.

However, in the world of Google Play, the most popular app store on Android, then each package name belongs to a developer account.

- If you generated the app with the App creator, and the app creator uploaded it to Google Play, then it will be associated with their developer account. You will also have other propblems, like it being signed with a signing key that they own, not you.
- if you generated the APK file with the App creator, and then downloaded it. Then you uploaded it to Google Play later, then the package name is associated with your developer account. You might still have problems with the signing key, unless you signed it yourself.

Any responsible App creator should let you transfer ownership, and also be prepared to let export the signing key. If they don't this is a problem. If this turns out to be the case, you might want to contact Google Play developer support to see if they can help you. I don't know what would be done in this scenario. If this is the case then I'd also share the name of the App creator in your question as a warning to other App developers.